# Edit text in file in python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I am new to python and working on to get input and edit a file with python. The value I want to edit is "web-iphone" with the text I get from input.

Code so far:

```
web = raw_input("Enter value")
```

The file: test.py

```
    local {
            value web-iphone
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Do I have to overwrite the file or is it possible to edit text in the file ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by edit - a file can be appended to, or parts can be replaced, it cannot be inserted to. Generally you want to over-write the file.

Comment: How can I replace the part "web-iphone" any resources I can look at ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123091/delete-a-line-from-a-file-in-place/27123361#27123361 lists basic ways in which you can edit a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: What you are asking is clearer now, refined my answer.

To get a file's contents:

```
def read_file(filename):
  return open(filename).read()
```

And to write to a file:

```
def write_file(filename, toWrite):
  file = open(filename, 'w')
  file.write(toWrite)
  file.close()
```

So to replace "web-iphone" with whatever the user typed in you could do:

```
Web = raw_input("Enter a value ")
Replaced = read_file("myfile.txt").replace("web-iphone", Web)
write_file("myfile.txt", Replaced)
```

For your comment:

```
newInput = raw_input("Enter a value ")
OldFile = read_file("myfile.txt")
value = OldFile.find("value"+6)
newFile = OldFile[:value] + newInput + OldFile[OldFile.find("\n",value+1):]
```

Comment: If I dont know the value to be replaced but I know the column? As in shell - awk '{ print $2  }' is that possible ? To replace a specific column in a line ?

Comment: It is possible, I will add it to the bottom of my answer for the sake of formatting, hold on a moment please.

Comment: Since I always want "value" in that file stay, but want to change the text after value to for example web-iphone.

Comment: Oh, ok . I'll have that added to my answer in a minute.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: No problem :) The code I just posted should replace anything after value, and before the next line, with the user input.

Comment: On the value+6 i get this error: 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Oops, move the +6 outside the parentheses.